# Requisições ajax com php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boa tarde, estou em processo de criação de um site para um trabalho, e me deparei com a situação que precisarei popular selects dinamicamente usando AJAX, JSON e PHP. Tem alguém que se disponha dar uma breve introdução. um exemplo seria, seleciono o estado SP e aparece as cidades.

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo um código acessando uma api via ajax e preenchendo os valores de um select, nos comentários expliquei melhor cada parte do código.

```js
//esta função do ajax é lida no carregamento da pagina
$(function () {  
  
  //este ajax faz o acesso 
  $.ajax({
  url: 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/',
  type: 'GET',
 })
 .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  //data é o retorno da api    
    //esse for percorre todo o retorno e pega o nome do obj   
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    
     //esta função está sendo usada para adicionar um elemento option em seu select e os valores deles são os dados retornados da api
     $("#estados").append("<option id='"+data[i].sigla+"'> "+data[i].nome+"</option>");
    }
    
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>pegar os dados desta api : https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/</h5>
<label>Preencha um estado:</label>
<!-- este select esta vazio e será preenchido via ajax -->
<select id="estados"></select>
```